# Return Display Name of profile property when using userprofileservice.asmx

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

In Central Admin, the profile property for *Responsibility* is configured this way:

[image: User Profile Property Edit]

When I call upon *GetUserProfileByName* using the User Profile Service, I get this back in the *responseXML*:

[image: Returned XML]

As you can see, only the *Name* ("*SPS-Responsibility*") is returned.
Is there a way for the *Display Name* ("*Responsibility*") to be returned in the XML as well?

This is the soap envelope I am using:

```
var soapEnv =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> \
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
 <soap:Body> \
    <GetUserProfileByName xmlns='http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService'> \
      <AccountName>domain\\username</AccountName> \
    </GetUserProfileByName> \
 </soap:Body> \
 </soap:Envelope>";
```

Comment: this might be too late question but it is related to what i have been trying to accomplish. The web service UserProfileService.asmx does not support OAuth2.0 token. It supports claim based authentication. Is there a way work around for this? Currently, i'm using CSOM but too bad its peoplemanager and userprofileloader methods return only the internal name of the properties but not the properties' friendly display name. UserProfileProperties Collection( SP.KeyValue ). Is there any Rest API which is behaving the same as UserProfileService.asmx get profile schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve property information including the display name via another method called GetUserProfileSchema:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcuserprofileservice.userprofileservice.getuserprofileschema(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: The default schema (0) is "UserProfile".